# jQuery Mobile Not Loading Page

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, formatting

My page doesn't seem to load when I include jQuery Mobile. I only receive a loading message that continues endlessly.  I separated my main PHP from my main HTML and I found that my editor can format the HTML correctly.  I have a feeling this has to do with HTML formatting, but I cannot find the problem.

```
        <html class="ui-mobile ui-loading"><head><base href="http://luvbid.com/admin/editauction.php?id=192&amp;offset=0">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.luvbid.com/admin/themes/default/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/simpledialog/latest/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
                // Navigation
                $.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnTheme = "d";
                // Page
                $.mobile.page.prototype.options.headerTheme = "b";
                // Page header only
                $.mobile.page.prototype.options.contentTheme = "c";
                $.mobile.page.prototype.options.footerTheme = "b";
                // Listviews
                $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.headerTheme = "b";
                // Header for nested lists
                $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.theme = "c";
                // List items / content
                $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.dividerTheme = "d";
                // List divider
                $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.splitTheme = "c";
                $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.countTheme = "c";
                $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.filterTheme = "c";
                $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.filterPlaceholder = "Filter data...";
                $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false;
            });

        </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/simpledialog/latest/jquery.mobile.simpledialog2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i8n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i8n.en.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/wysiwyg.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.luvbid.com/markitup/markitup/images/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.luvbid.com/admin/markitup/markitup/skins/markitup/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.luvbid.com/admin/markitup/markitup/sets/default/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="markitup/markitup/jquery.markitup.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.luvbid.com/admin/markitup/markitup/skins/markitup/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.luvbid.com/admin/markitup/markitup/sets/default/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="markitup/markitup/sets/default/set.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".markItUp").markItUp(mySettings);
            });

        </script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="chrome-extension://cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/style.css"><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="chrome-extension://cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/page_context.js"></script></head>
    <body class="ui-mobile-viewport" screen_capture_injected="true">
        <div data-role="page" data-url="/admin/editauction.php?id=192&amp;offset=0" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c">
            <div data-role="header" class="ui-header ui-bar-b" role="banner">
                                <a data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" href="index.php" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-up-b ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-inline="false" data-wrapperels="span" title="Home"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">Home</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home ui-icon-shadow"></span></span></a>
                                <div class="ui-title">
                    Luv Bid - Admin
                </div>
                                <a href="#menu" data-role="button" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-up-b ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-inline="false" data-wrapperels="span" title="Menu"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">Menu</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-grid ui-icon-shadow"></span></span></a>
                            </div>
            <div data-role="content" class="ui-content ui-body-c" role="main">
 <div>
    <form name="details" action="editauction.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br">
        <p>
            TITLE *     </p>
        <input type="text" name="title" size="40" maxlength="255" value="8GB iTouch">
        <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="0">
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br">
        <p>
            DESCRIPTION *       </p>
        <textarea class="markItUp" name="description" id="description">For information about the 8GB iTouch; visit the &lt;a href="http://www.apple.com"&gt;Apple Website&lt;/a&gt;.</textarea>
    </div>
    <!------------------------- item variants ------------------>
        <h3>Main Image</h3>
    <div>
                <a><img height="100px" width="100px" src="../uploaded/c88dfbd6733cc9fb31918c095cbbd380.jpg"></a>
        <div class="ui-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="delete_img" id="delete_img" value="delete"></div>
        <label for="delete">Delete</label>
                Max. 1024000000 bytes       <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1024000000">
    </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br">
        <p>
            Worth       </p>
        <input type="text" name="item_value" size="40" maxlength="40" value="229.00">
        <label>USD</label>
    </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br">
        <p>
            Bid Price       </p>
        <input type="text" name="bid_value" size="40" maxlength="40" value="1.00">
        USD     <input type="hidden" readonly="" name="min_bid" size="40" value="0.01">
        <input type="hidden" name="min_bid" size="40" maxlength="40" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="min_bid" size="40" maxlength="40" value="0.0000">
        <input type="hidden" name="min_bid" size="40" maxlength="40" value="0.0000">
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity" size="40" maxlength="40" value="1">
        <input readonly="" type="hidden" name="current_bid" size="15" maxlength="15" value="0.0000">
            </div>
    <input type="submit" onclick="updateTextArea('description');" name="act" value="Process changes">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="192">
    <input type="hidden" name="offset" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update">
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div> <div id="menu" data-role="page" data-url="menu">
    <div data-role="header">
        <div class="ui-title">
            Menu
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li>
                <div class="ui-title">
                    Settings                </div>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li>
                        <a href="settings.php">General Settings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="batch.php">Batch Procedures Settings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="picturesupload.php">Pictures Upload</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="errorhandling.php">Error Handling</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="countries.php">Countries Table</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="languages.php">Languages</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="durations.php">Auctions Duration</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="categories.php">Categories Table</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="ui-title">
                    Preferences             </div>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li>
                        <a href="currency.php">Currencies Settings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="time.php">Time Settings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="dates.php">Dates Format</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="defaultcountry.php">Default country</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="metatags.php">HTML meta Tags</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="ui-title">
                    Users               </div>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li>
                        <a href="newadminuser.php">New admin user</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="adminusers.php">Admin users management</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="acceptancetext.php">Acceptance Text</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="listusers.php">Users management</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="activatenewsletter.php">Newsletter</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="newsletter.php">Newsletter Submission</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="banips.php">IP Addresses</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="news.php">News Management</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="ui-title">
                    Auctions                </div>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li>
                        <a href="sell.php">Add new auction</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="listallauctions.php">All auctions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="listauctions.php">View Open Auctions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="listclosedauctions.php">View Closed Auctions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="listsuspendedauctions.php">View Suspended Auctions</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="../webim/operator/index.php" target="_new">Live Support</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-loading"></span><h1>loading</h1></div></body></html>
```

UPDATE: Showing rendered HTML instead.

Comment: How about just giving us the HTML that is returned from the server to the web browser.

Comment: Really though, this is a bit much, if you think it's the HTML structure that's getting you, just post the rendered HTML (post PHP).

Comment: This is almost certainly a JS/HTML issue. This code is mostly unhelpful.

Comment: Now, I am showing the rendered HTML instead.

Comment: There appears to be an error when initializing form input widgets. Check to make sure you have properly structured your forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was a `label` tag that had a `for` attribute that was not correct:

```
<label for="delete">Delete</label>
```

Should be:

```
<label for="delete_img">Delete</label>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zcUs2/

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if its your problem at all, but `<!------------------------- item variants ------------------>` is a bad way to put in html comments.

I dont have a ref right now, but I think the logic is something like this:

the actual 'comment' code is "--" so you are essentially comment/uncommenting over and over.

use `<!--==================================-->` or something else instead

---

**EDIT**:
Found an article:  http://weblog.200ok.com.au/2008/01/dashing-into-trouble-why-html-comments.html

Comment: OK I fixed that, but that's not my problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I generally don't use HTML comments, but this is good to know. My fix (even though I didn't know it) is to minify/obfuscate all code before it reaches production (which removes all comments). http://htmlcompressor.com/